# singly linked list in C: pushBack

Tags: c

I have to create the pushBack method that will add an element to the end of my list, but the pushBack method that it implements does not work. Below I leave the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int *data;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct
{
    // Puntero al primer nodo
    Node *head;
    // Cantidad de datos
    unsigned short size;
    // Puntero al ultimo dato accedido.
    Node *current;
}List;

List *createList();
Node *createNode(int *);
void pushBack(List *, int *);

int main(void)
{
    List *lista = createList();
    pushBack(&lista, 4);
    return 0;
}


List *createList()
{
    List *list = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));
    list -> head = NULL;
    list -> size = 0;
    list -> current = NULL;
    return list;
}

Node *createNode(int *data)
{
    Node *node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node -> data = data;
    node -> next = NULL;
    return node;
}
// Función para insertar un nuevo nodo al final de la lista
void pushBack(List *list, int *data)
{
    Node *node = createNode(data);
    while ( list -> head )
        list -> head = list -> head -> next;
    list -> head = node;
    list -> size ++;
}
```

any correction in the pushBack method would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you changing the *`head`* pointer of the list?

Answer (score 2):

With respect to your current code:

```
void pushBack(List *list, int *data)
{
    Node *node = createNode(data);
    while ( list -> head )
        list -> head = list -> head -> next;
    list -> head = node;
    list -> size ++;
}
```

Pushing something on to the back of a list should only ever change the head ***if the list was previously empty.*** What you're doing is actually corrupting the list by moving its head where it should not be.

You *may* have meant to use `current` rather than `head` (after first setting it to `head` of course) but it's unusual to dedicate a field for that within the list itself - you usually just use a temporary variable.

You would be far better off storing the tail as well so that you don't have to search for it each time<sup>(a)</sup>. But, assuming that's not an option, the following pseudo-code should help you out:

```
def push_back(list, item):
    # Force tail constraints, new tail must be end of list.

    item.next = null

    # If list empty, simply set head.

    if list.head == null:
        list.head = item
        return

    # Find last element in list:

    curr = list.head
    while curr.next != null:
        curr = curr.next

    # Now have last, just attach new item to it.

    curr.next = item
```

Turning that into C, I'll leave as an exercise for the reader. You should be doing at least *some* of your homework :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're interested in how to do that, see below:

```
def push_back(list, item):
    # Force tail constraints, new tail must be end of list.

    item.next = null

    # If list empty, simply set head/tail.

    if list.head == null:
        list.head = item
        list.tail = item
        return

    # In non-empty list, tail will always be last element.

    curr.tail.next = item   # Point current tail to new tail.
    curr.tail = item        # Update tail
```